# Date field display at drupal 7

Tags: php, html, drupal-7

I am new at Drupal 7 and i have a problem. I use Date module and i
have a content type with a date field(day-month-year). When i display the date i get
something like this:

```
<div class="...">12 04 2014</div>
```

I am ok with that. The problem is that the whole date value is wrapped with
a div and for design reasons i want each value to be on its own tag,  like this:

```
<div class="foo">12</div>  
<div class="voo">04</div>  
<div class="moo">2014</div>
```

Any suggestions?